# Pip install error

Tags: python, pip

I try (desperately) to install any package using pip but I get the same error all the time!
Here is my version of pip:

```
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

And my version of python:

```
Python 2.7.6
```

And the error when i try to install new package:

[image]

If you have an idea to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you recently upgrade your version of Ubuntu?
You are probably experiencing [a bug in the Ubuntu upgrade process](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1375357).
Try running:

```
sudo pip install --no-use-wheel --upgrade distribute
```

Just a thought moving forward, have you looked into [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html)?

Comment: Yep, i have upgrade my ubuntu yesterday... And it work prefectly!! thanks you =)

Comment: Edits accepted with small modification to add link for virtualenv